# Reuse translations in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm wondering if it's possible to reuse Localization translations in Laravel 5.2. So something like this, or better real global accesable keys to direct use `brand`, instead of typing the folder or file name (In this example `global`).

```
// resources/lang/en/global.php
return [
 'brand' => 'Stackoverflow',
 'my'    => 'My :attribute',
 'my_brand' => trans('global.my', ['attribute' => trans('global.brand')])
];
```

Hope their is a way to reuse translations with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a View Composer to inject your translations globally into all the views of the application. The steps you should follow are the following.

- Create a view composer
- Register the view composer to a Service Provider
- Inject your translations into the composer and bind it to all views using the wildcard operator.

The composer class should look like this and it's namespace should be App\Http\ViewComposers (App can be different based on the namespace of your application)

```
class TranslationsComposer
    {
        protected $translations;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->translations = [
                'brand' => trans('global.brand'),
                'my' => trans('global.my'),
            ];
        }

        public function compose(View $view)
        {
             $view->with('translations', $this->translations);
        }
    }
```

You could use a loop to get the translations but this is a simple example just to demonstrate the way.

Now for the service provider you should use something like this

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Users\Repository as UserRepository;
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
           '*','App\Http\ViewComposers\TranslationsComposer'
        );
    }

    public function register()
    {
      //
    }
}
```

After doing so you should be able to use these variables as {{translations.brand}} in your blade templates.

You can find more about view composers at the official Laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views

Comment: That sounds like a idea, but I want to say it like `trans('brand')`. I don't know if this also can provide a way to reuse translation in the translation file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own helper file to resolve the lang variable.

Step 1: Create a file with .php extension in App\Helpers. Any file name (with .php extension) should load automatically by Helper ServiceProvider. In your HelperServiceProvider you should find some code as below:

```
public function register()
    {
        foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
            require_once($filename);
        }

    }
```

Step 2: Create a function in your new helper file as below:

```
if(! function_exists('my_trans')){
    function my_trans($key){
        // load all the lang variable as an array here which should look like as below
        $lang = [
            'key1'=>'value1',
            'key2'=>'value2',
            'key3'=>'value3',
            'key4'=>'value4',
            'key5'=>'value5'
        ];

        return $lang[$key];
    }
}
```

Step 3: Call the function with key from your blade file as below:

```
{{my_trans('key2')}}
```

This is working example and should help you to extend your idea.